# Use libmysql.dll dynamically in C++ application

Tags: c++, mysql, dynamic, connector

I use MySql C++ connector in my project on Visual C++ 2010.
In Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies I wrote mysqlcppconn-static.lib and libmysql.lib.
So, libmysql.dll is required for my application. I want to make my application workable without libmysql.dll (features that require connection to MySql DB will be disabled).
How can I do that?

UPD. I found the solution: Delay Load Import (/DELAYLOAD). [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) (I'm not a Windows developer, *I just googled it...*)

Comment: I want to continue using MySQL C++ Connector, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, dll is loaded only after any function inside dll is called by application at runtime.
You can use LoadLibrary()  if you want to control when you want to use.

Comment: Mysql C++ connector (mysqlcppconn-static.lib) uses libmysql.lib, I'm unable to use LoadLibrary in it.

Comment: If you want to use dll , can you use mysqlcppconn.lib instead of static?
I dont have experiece with mysqlcppconn but I guess  you shopuld change that linker line to mysqlcppconn.lib and remove mysqlcppconn-static.lib

Comment: No. I want to use static mysqlcppconn-static.lib. Otherwise need 2 dlls for application: mysqlcppconn.dll and libmysql.dll.

Comment: when you load mysqlcppconn.dll , the libmysql.dll will be loaded by runtime